# JavaMailSender works in test but not on website

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using JavaMailSender in my SpringBoot project which is deployed via AWS ElasticBeanstalk. Sending emails via the JavaMailSender works when it's done as a part of a unit test. But when the same code is ran on the website, I get an error.

```
Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.
Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
```

I followed the instructions. I made sure the password is correct. I enabled access by the less-secure applications. I tried two different account. The result is always the same. Unit tests work, website doesn't.

This is my code:

```
@Service
public class SpringEmailSender {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername("email");
        mailSender.setPassword("password");

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class BusinessLogic {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private SpringEmailSender springEmailSender;

    public boolean sendAccountValidationEmail(User user) {
        JavaMailSender javaMailSender = springEmailSender.getJavaMailSender();
        try {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            String emailBody = String.format(EmailBodyTemplates.ACCOUNT_VALIDATION_EMAIL.getEmailBody(), user.getUsername(), user.getUsername());
            mimeMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
            mimeMessage.setSubject(EmailBodyTemplates.ACCOUNT_VALIDATION_EMAIL.getEmailSubject());
            mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(user.getUsername()));
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);

        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Any idea why I am getting the error when sending email on the website?

Comment: Have you created a password for the app as described on https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?

Comment: This sometimes solves the issue - https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps. But seems like the preferred way to send email is via Google API or over OAuth2.

Comment: I don't have the "App Passwords" option in my Google security settings. Is it maybe because I don't have this app registered at Google? Should be working anyway. I have the "less secure apps" enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a new Gmail account and using that. After activating less secure apps on the new account, it started working.

Another option was suggested to me on the Gmail forums. I didn't test this solution:
"Gmail doesn't recognise the device or IP from the Java program, so it is trying to verify your identity.  The easiest way to work around it is to enable 2-step verification on your Google account, so you can use an App Password for SMTP authentication."